# Terraform: Local list of maps iteration with for_each and conditionals

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I want to define a list of maps inside a variable so I can use **for_each** on multiple resources with conditionals based on the key values.

For example I have this **locals.tf** file where I define the list of maps

```
locals {
  networking = [
    {
      name = "first"
      domain = "first.${local.dns_name}"
      port = 8080
      group = "eighties"

    },
    {
      name = "second"
      domain = "second.${local.dns_name}"
      port = 8081
      group = "eighties"
    },
    {
      name = "third"
      domain = "third.${local.dns_name}"
      port = 9090
      group = "nineties"
    },
    {
      name = "fourth"
      port = 9091
      group = "nineties"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my other file, I can loop through the list of maps with **for_each** and **for** arguments:

```
resource "google_dns_record_set" "dns_records" {
  for_each     = { 
    for k in local.networking: k.domain => k
    if k.domain != null
  }
  name         = each.value.domain
  type         = "A"
  ttl          = 300
  managed_zone = var.managed_zone
  project      = var.dns_project
  rrdatas      = [google_compute_global_address.default-forwarding-address.address]
}
```

Given this setup, I have 2 different situations that I might discuss:

1. Since the domain key doesn't exists for the fourth map, Terraform just stops.

Is it possible to skip the resource creations if **domain** does not exist in the fourth map? Or simply skip the errors.

`Error: Unsupported attribute on dns-record.tf line 4, in resource "google_dns_record_set" "dns_records": 4: if k.domain != null This object does not have an attribute named "domain".`

2. If I change the **k.domain** values for **k.group** and the conditional to be something like `k.group == "eighties"` so I can target a specific group, I receive this duplication error.

`Two different items produced the key "eighties" in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.`

Are this errors manageable with the current setup or should I drop the list of maps idea?

Comment: Are you certain that error is thrown for the second resource? It seems much more like it would be thrown for the first resource.

Comment: Hey @MattSchuchard . Yeah it's thrown by the second resource

Comment: I share Matt Schuchard's suspicion here. Your first example shows a `local.networking` value that is defined as a tuple, which is invalid and would produce the error message you showed. The second example shows a `for` expression projecting that tuple into a map of objects, which would make the error message you showed impossible because the result of that `for` expression cannot possibly be a tuple. It might help if you show the entire error message rather than just the two lines you picked out, since that will include the snippet showing exactly what code Terraform is complaining about.

Comment: @MartinAtkins you and Matt are actually right. I made a silly mistake before asking this question, basically the error was triggered by `for_each = local.networking` in another file with similar naming and also I didn't paid attention to the code that Terraform outputs

Comment: However, I might have some other questions regarding this, should I add and EDIT 1 to the question above?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to be as complete/correct as possible a description of your current situation and the problem you are facing. Nobody has answered yet, so there's no harm in changing the details of the question to make it answerable! 

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks Martin, I made the full edit of the body content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `domain` exist as follows:

```
{ 
    for k in local.networking: k.domain => k
    if contains(keys(k), "domain")
}
```